# Will a small investment in a company net a worthwhile gain?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, shares, investment-strategies

If I invest 4-5 shares in a company valued at around 20 dollars each share would I see a profit in my investment or is that too small of an investment to see a gain and therefore a waste of time?

Answer (score 5):

If the shares rise in value 50% over the next few years, you will have the same return that I would see if I bought 100 or 1000 shares. 
The only issue with a small purchase is that even a $5 commission is a high percent. But the rest of the math is the same.

Comment: What if I brought 10 shares at 200 what would the break even point be?

Comment: Still a $1 rise, but $1 on a $200 stock is just 1/2%.

Answer (score 3):

If you bought 5 shares @ $20 each that would cost you $100 plus brokerage. Even if your brokerage was only $10 in and out, your shares would have to go up 20% just for you to break even.

You don't make a profit until you sell, so just for you to break even your shares need to go up to $24 per share.

Because your share holding would be so small the brokerage, even the cheapest around, would end up being a large percentage cost of any overall profits. If instead you had bought 500 shares at $20, being $1000, the $20 brokerage (in and out) only represents 2% instead of 20%. This is called economies of scale.

Comment: And yet, if the shares were Apple, and the stock went up 100X, the $20 would seem like mouse nuts.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - true, but how often does that happen? A bit like a lottery sometimes.

Comment: Robinhood to the rescue! :p (Seriously, Robinhood changes that cost calculation completely - no fees to make simple stock trades is a game-changer. Not the greatest interface ever, but still. Free.)

Comment: @Victor, I was writing that half tongue-in-cheek. My answer was similar to yours. I stopped from going down the "buy index funds/ETFs" route. If one is determined to buy individual stocks, I'd suggest they are actually better off buying $200 worth of 5 different stocks and learn what they are doing with low money at risk.

Comment: @neminem - if Robinhood is so good why are not more people using them? What is their catch if any?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - your previous comment actually reminded me of a situation where a father bought his small son a couple of shares in a company for his first birthday. About 50 years later the son finds the share certificates in an old box going through his fathers things after he passed away and found out the shares were worth a small fortune (a few hundred thousand dollars).

Comment: @Victor They're pretty new still, they're smartphone app only (and for a while they only had an ios app, though they do have Android now as well), and the interface is... pretty basic, as is the feature set. Plus, probably some people just don't *trust* "free".

Comment: There is another Question about Robinhood; see the answers to that, or open a new Question, rather than digressing here.